# Drop down list works only the first time when I click then it doesn't change the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a script that should automatically change the value when drop down list selection is changed, and it works first time I change the value, but second time it does not work (after I try to select different value from the one I selected previously)

Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="search" placeholder="Search..." type="text"/> 

<label for="showbrand" class="filter">Brand:<select id="showbrand" data-bind=''>
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="">All</option>
</select></label>
<label for="showfrom" class="filter">From:<input type="date" id="showfrom"></label>
<label for="showto" class="filter">To:<input type="date" id="showto"></label>           
<a id="filterList" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" onclick="clickFilter();">Find</a><table id="dataTable" class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Campaign</th>
<th>Brand</th>
<th>Starts On</th>
<th>Ends On</th>
<th>Files</th>
<th>Edit</th>   
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="msg"></div>
```

JS:

```
$("#showbrand").change(function(){
var info = new Array();
info[0] = $("#showbrand").val();
if($("#showfrom").val() !== '' && 
$("#showto").val() !== ''){
info[1] = 'yes';
}
else{
info[1] = 'no';
}
info[2] = $("#showfrom").val();
info[3] = $("#showto").val();
info[4] = $("#search").val();

listCampaignsFiltered(info, 'dataTable', 0);
});



unction listCampaignsFiltered(info, tableName, limit){
var params = "&brand="+info[0]+
"&daterange="+info[1]+
"&from="+info[2]+
"&to="+info[3]+
"&limit="+limit+
"&search="+info[4];
$.getJSON(LOCAL_URI+"?action=campaignfiltered"+params, function(result) {
//console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
$('#'+tableName+" tbody").html('');
if(result.length > 0){
$("#msg").html(result.length+ " Records found.");
$.each(result, function(){
var $tr = '<tr><td>'+ this.campaign + "</td><td>"+
this.brandName+"</td><td>"+this.startson+
"</td><td>"+ this.endson +"</td></tr>";    
$('#'+tableName+" tbody").append($tr);
});
}
else{
$("#msg").html('No records found.');
}
});
}
```

Comment: You need to add the value into the array each time you change the select right ?

Comment: If you add blank value in both the item of option list so every time it return blank string.  Like  <select id="showbrand" data-bind=''> <option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="">All</option> </select>

Answer (score 1):

For your `select` element to change, you might need distinct values, otherwise no matter what you choose as your `option`, it'll always have the same value.

I've never setup a `select` element without values so I'm not 100% sure this is your issue. Please let me know if this happens to be the issue, otherwise I'll remove the answer.

Also, your JS needs a closing `)` to be valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The values I am using are dynamic so the user can add any value to the drop down list. I will post the whole script

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should assign the value in dropdown and also correct your syntax in jquery.
I think below code will help you

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#showbrand").change(function () {
        var info = new Array();
        info[0] = $("#showbrand").val();
        alert(info[0]);
    });
    });

</script>

<label for="showbrand" class="filter">Brand:
 <select id="showbrand" data-bind=''>
    <option value="1">--select--</option>
    <option value="2">test</option>
    <option value="3">All</option>
 </select>
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The values I am using are dynamic because the user can add any value to the drop down list so I don't think this would be the issue.. I will post the whole script